# Unresolved SBT dependency com.google.errorprone#error_prone_annotations;[2.3.2,2.3.3]: not found

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy, errorprone

I am trying to add the errorprone dependency via sbt, and it is having trouble resolving one of the errorprone dependencies. I am new to Java/Scala development and will really appreciate your help! The following is the error i am getting.

`[error] (providers / update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.google.errorprone#error_prone_annotations;[2.3.2,2.3.3]: not found [error] download failed: com.google.errorprone#error_prone_annotations;2.3.2!error_prone_annotations.jar [error] Total time: 10 s, completed Aug 13, 2020 10:40:27 AM`

Comment: How did you include it? Is this the only dependency that fails? - In any case, are you sure that thing works with **Scala** and that the way to use it is to add it as a dependency?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's a  transitive dependency its being included by any of the libraries in use. I am not sure which one it is using!!!

Comment: Try including it yourself explicitly to see what happens: `libraryDependencies += "com.google.errorprone" % "error_prone_annotations" % "2.3.3"`.

Comment: You can use the plugin bellow to analyse the dependency tree to find out which of your dependencies is using the unresolved dependency:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph

Comment: I resolved it!!! I had an issue with my local environment setup as i am working behind a proxy i had to add proxy configuration in my git settings.
    
 `git config --global http.proxy http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>`
`git config --global https.proxy https://<my_proxy>:<my_port>`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it!!!

I had an issue with my local environment setup as i am working behind a proxy i had to add proxy configuration in my git settings.

`git config --global http.proxy http://<my_proxy>:<my_port>`

`git config --global https.proxy https://<my_proxy>:<my_port>`